# How to combine sql statements from 2 tables

Tags: sql

I have two sql statements that work:

```
select firstName from table1 s INNER JOIN  table2 t ON s.LoginId = t.userId
```

and

```
select testScore from table2 where userId in (select loginId from table1)
```

How can I combine the statements so

```
firstName
```

from the first statement is added to the output of the second statement (i.e. the output produces firstName and testScore?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to `JOIN` the two tables. You're already doing this, so perhaps there's some information or requirement missing from your question as to why the following wouldn't work?

```
SELECT s.firstName, t.testScore
FROM table1 s
INNER JOIN table2 t ON (s.LoginId = t.userId)
```